# Add birthday field to WooCommerce my account and admin user page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, account, user-data

I have added the code below. The birthday field is showing in my account page and also in WP admin user page as well but **the problem is that the date is not saving**.

What I have so far

```php
function iconic_get_account_fields() {
return apply_filters( 'iconic_account_fields', array(
    'user_url' => array(
        'type'        => 'date',
        'label'       => __( 'My Birth Date', 'iconic' ),
        'placeholder' => __( 'Date of Birth', 'iconic' ),
        'required'    => true,
    ),
) );
}
/**
* Add fields to registration form and account area.

*/
function iconic_print_user_frontend_fields() {
$fields = iconic_get_account_fields();

foreach ( $fields as $key => $field_args ) {
    woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field_args );
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'iconic_print_user_frontend_fields', 10 ); // my account

 /**
 * Add fields to admin area.
 */
function iconic_print_user_admin_fields() {
$fields = iconic_get_account_fields();
?>
<h2><?php _e( 'Additional Information', 'iconic' ); ?></h2>
<table class="form-table" id="iconic-additional-information">
    <tbody>
    <?php foreach ( $fields as $key => $field_args ) { ?>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <label for="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $field_args['label']; ?></label>
            </th>
            <td>
                <?php $field_args['label'] = false; ?>
                <?php woocommerce_form_field( $key, $field_args ); ?>
            </td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 <?php
 }


 add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'iconic_print_user_admin_fields', 30 ); // admin: edit profile
 add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'iconic_print_user_admin_fields', 30 ); // admin: edit other users
```

---

I use the code partly from:

[The Ultimate Guide to Adding Custom WooCommerce Registration Fields](https://iconicwp.com/blog/the-ultimate-guide-to-adding-custom-woocommerce-user-account-fields/)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code will add (and save) a custom birthday field to

- My account - edit account
- Admin user page - profile

```php
// Add field - my account
function action_woocommerce_edit_account_form() {   
    woocommerce_form_field( 'birthday_field', array(
        'type'        => 'date',
        'label'       => __( 'My Birth Date', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder' => __( 'Date of Birth', 'woocommerce' ),
        'required'    => true,
    ), get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'birthday_field', true ));
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_edit_account_form', 'action_woocommerce_edit_account_form' );

// Validate - my account
function action_woocommerce_save_account_details_errors( $args ){
    if ( isset($_POST['birthday_field']) && empty($_POST['birthday_field']) ) {
        $args->add( 'error', __( 'Please provide a birth date', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details_errors','action_woocommerce_save_account_details_errors', 10, 1 );

// Save - my account
function action_woocommerce_save_account_details( $user_id ) {  
    if( isset($_POST['birthday_field']) && ! empty($_POST['birthday_field']) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'birthday_field', sanitize_text_field($_POST['birthday_field']) );
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_account_details', 'action_woocommerce_save_account_details', 10, 1 );

// Add field - admin
function add_user_birtday_field( $user ) {
    ?>
        <h3><?php _e('Birthday','woocommerce' ); ?></h3>
        <table class="form-table">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="birthday_field"><?php _e( 'Date of Birth', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label></th>
                <td><input type="date" name="birthday_field" value="<?php echo esc_attr( get_the_author_meta( 'birthday_field', $user->ID )); ?>" class="regular-text" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br />
    <?php
}
add_action( 'show_user_profile', 'add_user_birtday_field', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile', 'add_user_birtday_field', 10, 1 );

// Save field - admin
function save_user_birtday_field( $user_id ) {
    if( ! empty($_POST['birthday_field']) ) {
        update_user_meta( $user_id, 'birthday_field', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['birthday_field'] ) );
    }
}
add_action( 'personal_options_update', 'save_user_birtday_field', 10, 1 );
add_action( 'edit_user_profile_update', 'save_user_birtday_field', 10, 1 );
```