# Birthday field in the WooCommerce "My account" registration form is not saved

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Together with fields for the first and last name of the customer, I added to the WooCommerce "My account" registration form a custom birthday field, in fact 3 `select` tags. The problem is that, for some reasons, the birthday is not saved. **What is wrong in my code?**

I mention that, for my reasons, I don't want to use an `input` field for birthday.

```
/** Add custom fields to the "My account" customer registration form **/
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_form_start', function() { 
    ?>
    <p class="form-row form-row-first-name">
        <label for="billing_first_name"><?php _e( 'First name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_first_name" id="billing_first_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <p class="form-row form-row-last-name">
        <label for="billing_last_name"><?php _e( 'Last name', 'woocommerce' ); ?><span class="required">*</span></label>
        <input type="text" class="input-text" name="billing_last_name" id="billing_last_name" value="<?php if ( ! empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) esc_attr_e( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ); ?>" />
    </p>

    <table class="form-table">
        <tr>
            <th><label for="birth-date-day"><?php echo __( 'Birthday' ); ?></label></th>
            <td>
                <select id="birth-date-day" name="birthday[day]">
                    <option selected="selected" value=""><?php echo __( 'Day' ); ?></option><?php
                    for( $i = 1; $i <= 31; $i++ ) {
                        printf( '<option value="%1$s">%1$s</option>', $i );
                    } ?>
                </select>

                <select id="birth-date-month" name="birthday[month]">
                    <option selected="selected" value=""><?php echo __( 'Month' ); ?></option>
                    <option><?php echo __( 'January' ); ?></option>
                    <option><?php echo __( 'February' ); ?></option>
                    <option><?php echo __( 'March' ); ?></option>
                    <option><?php echo __( 'April' ); ?></option>
                    <option><?php echo __( 'May' ); ?></option>
                    <option><?php echo __( 'June' ); ?></option>
                    <option><?php echo __( 'July' ); ?></option>
                    <option><?php echo __( 'August' ); ?></option>
                    <option><?php echo __( 'September' ); ?></option>
                    <option><?php echo __( 'October' ); ?></option>
                    <option><?php echo __( 'November' ); ?></option>
                    <option><?php echo __( 'December' ); ?></option>
                </select>

                <select id="birth-date-year" name="birthday[year]">
                    <option selected="selected" value=""><?php echo __( 'Year' ); ?></option><?php
                    for( $i = date("Y") - 14; $i >= date("Y") - 99 ; $i-- ) {
                        printf( '<option value="%1$s">%1$s</option>', $i );
                    } ?>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <?php
} );

/** Validate "My account" registration form custom fields **/
add_action( 'woocommerce_register_post', function( $username, $email, $validation_errors ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_first_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: First name is required!', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) && empty( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'billing_last_name_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Last name is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['birthday'] ) && empty( $_POST['birthday'] ) ) {
        $validation_errors->add( 'birthday_error', __( '<strong>Error</strong>: Birthday is required!.', 'woocommerce' ) );
    }

    return $validation_errors;
}, 10, 3 );


/** Save "My account" registratio form extra fields **/
add_action( 'woocommerce_created_customer', function( $customer_id ) {
    if( isset( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_first_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_first_name'] ) );
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) ) {
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'billing_last_name', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['billing_last_name'] ) );
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['birthday'] ) ) {
        // convert from array to 'd F Y' date format string
        $birthday = implode( ' ', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['birthday'] ) );
        $birthday = str_replace( ' ', '', $birthday ); // strip spaces

        // convert from 'd F Y' string to 'Y-m-d' date format
        $birthday = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $birthday ) );

        update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'birthday', $birthday );
    }
} );
```

Comment: The issue is because you have 3 separated fields (day, month, year) and you only handle 1 field while saving. If you want to make it easier on yourself, you can use a date field instead, see [Add birthday field to WooCommerce my account and admin user page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62140927/11987538)

Comment: @7uc1f3r I know about that solution, but, as I know, it has an inconvenience - the language of the displayed calendar, as I know, is decided by the browser, not by the developer. Or not?  My site is not in English.

Answer (score 0):

I changed a little the `select` part for month and the saving part for birthday and now my code works, so I have in the database the birthday in the `yyyy-mm-dd` format.

```
<select id="birth-date-month" name="birthday[month]" />
    <option selected="selected" value=""><?php echo __( 'Month' ); ?></option>
    <option value="1"><?php _e( 'January' ); ?></option>
    <option value="2"><?php _e( 'February' ); ?></option>
    <option value="3"><?php _e( 'March' ); ?></option>
    <option value="4"><?php _e( 'April' ); ?></option>
    <option value="5"><?php _e( 'May' ); ?></option>
    <option value="6"><?php _e( 'June' ); ?></option>
    <option value="7"><?php _e( 'July' ); ?></option>
    <option value="8"><?php _e( 'August' ); ?></option>
    <option value="9"><?php _e( 'September' ); ?></option>
    <option value="10"><?php _e( 'October' ); ?></option>
    <option value="11"><?php _e( 'November' ); ?></option>
    <option value="12"><?php _e( 'December' ); ?></option>
</select>

if( isset( $_POST['birthday'] ) ) {
    // convert from array to 'd F Y' date format string
    $birthday = implode( '-', $_POST['birthday'] );

    // convert from 'd F Y' string to 'Y-m-d' date format
    $birthday = date( 'Y-m-d', strtotime( $birthday ) );

    update_user_meta( $customer_id, 'birthday', $birthday );
}
```